# Sub Columns in SP 2013

Tags: custom-field-types

I have a list set up with several columns. One of the columns, "Area of Focus", has several options to choose from. I would like to set up a list to make a Sub Column, "Tactics", so that when an individual chooses a particular item in Area of Focus they have choices in Tactics that only pertains to that particular Area of Focus. I am fairly new to SharePoint and very new to creating lists etc. Any help offered is GREATLY appreciated.